Windows Server 2016: Extending a Volume that has been Configured for Data Deduplication
Greetings All,
Does someone know about possible pitfalls to consider, when extending a Volume that is configured for Data Deduplication but ran out of space?
Objective
Extend a data deduplicated Volume by additional 500 GB
Specifics
OS: Windows Server 2016 Enterprise
Raid Type: 5
Purpose of the Volume: Hosting Hyper-V Files
Number of VMs: 15
Volume Size: 500 GB
Steps in Mind
Disable Data Deduplication
Copy all files to an external drive (primitive "backup" approach)
Extend the Volume
Enable Data Deduplication
Info
The server is used in a private lab environment with no Server Backup implemented
Any recommendations on how to approach the issue is highly appreciated
Note

Excuse me, if the question is not stated correctly
I am not a Windows Administrator by profession


In Windows Server 2016, extending a volume that has been configured for Data Deduplication requires careful steps to ensure the integrity of the data. First, verify that the volume is in good health and that deduplication is running smoothly. You can do this by checking the Data Deduplication status using PowerShell or Server Manager. Before proceeding, it's a good idea to pause deduplication jobs to prevent conflicts during the extension process.
To extend the volume, open the Disk Management tool or use PowerShell commands. In Disk Management, right-click on the volume and select “Extend Volume.” Follow the prompts to add unallocated space to the existing volume

Thanks for the response !!!
I will follow your advice and let you know abut the result :-)
